# How can I spawn and unspawn chunks of tiles while the player moves through an infinite game world?

Tags: unity, procedural

I have a procedural generated 100x100 land. I want to spawn it infinitely as the player moves on the horizontal axis, and also disappear if the player is too far. The way I generated the land is a bit weird. First I generated the plain 100x100 with sprites. Each sprite has a chance of spawning a sprites (like rock or cactus).

How can I spawn those chucks if the player moves closer to the chuck and disappear if the player moves farther away?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common design for large worlds.

You can test the distance between the player and the positions of your different chunks frequently. You also have to set a maximum distance when a chunk is loaded.

Then, it's a very simple condition:

- When the distance is less than maximum distance, you load the chunk.
- If a chunk is loaded and the distance is greater than maximum distance, you unload the chunk.

You can calculate the distance with a simple Pythagorean theorem or just use Unity's [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html).

You first need some struct or class to represent your chunks:

```cs
public struct Chunk {
    public string name;
    public bool loaded = false;
}
```

Then, you can create an empty GameObject that will handle the chunk management. Here is a very rough outline to give you a direction, but you will have to fine tune it to fit the specific needs of your project.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ChunksLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dictionary <Vector3, Chunk> chunks;
    public GameObject player;
    public float maximumDistance = 50f;

    void Awake()
    {
        chunks = new Dictionary<Vector3, Chunk>();
    }

    public void PopulateChunks() {
        /* You populate your dictionary here, as a custom editor is not needed since you generate your world.
        You can call this function when your procedural generation is finished, for example. */
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 playerPosition = player.transform.position;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Vector3, Chunk> chunk in chunks) {
            if (chunk.Value.loaded == false && Vector3.Distance(chunk.Key, playerPosition) < 50f) {
                StartCoroutine(LoadChunk(chunk.Value));
            } else if (chunk.Value.loaded) {
                StartCoroutine(UnloadChunk(chunk.Value));
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoadChunk(Chunk chunk) {
        AsyncOperation async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(chunk.name, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
        while (!async.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        chunk.loaded = true;
    }

    IEnumerator UnloadChunk(Chunk chunk) {
        AsyncOperation async = SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(chunk.name);
        while (!async.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        chunk.loaded = false;
    }
}
```

I didn't make many optimizations and this will need adjustments to work in your project. However, one of the most important optimizations (and a very simple one) is to test the bool `loaded` *before* checking the distance, since you can avoid this way some unneeded computations.

The two IEnumerator will also need adjustments to fit your needs. You can find a few examples [in the official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html).

For the infinite "loop" of your world's chunks you can just use a modulo operator on your player coordinates but it depends on how you want it to be infinite.

Comment: Will this work for 2d as well after some things like vector3 to vector 2

Comment: Of course! You just have to change Vector3 to Vector2. Going from 3D to 2D is always possible, as you can just "ignore" the Z position. The other way round is not always possible. That's why I suggested a 3D example, as it could be adapted easily to your needs, whether you're making a 3D or a 2D game. Vector2.Distance() works the same as Vector3.Distance().